# Flutter Provider dependency

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

How to create a provider depending on another provider?

Basically, after my user login, the home screen need to display 2 different info:

- his user profile name,
- his current week info from a program of 9 weeks.

the current week is located in his user profile, therefore i need this first before I can use to the currentWeekProvider. How can we achieve this ordering and dependency?

I have then two providers:

```dart
final userProfileProvider = FutureProvider<UserProfile>((ref) async {
  final repository = ref.watch(hopeRepositoryProvider);
  UserProfile user = await repository.getUserProfile();  
  return user;
  
});
```

```dart
final programProvider = FutureProvider<HopeProgram>((ref) async {
  final repository = ref.read(hopeRepositoryProvider);
  final user = ref.watch(userProfileProvider);  
  HopeProgram program = await repository.getCurrentWeekProgram(user.currentWeek); // does not work, the compile complain
  return program;
});
``
```

Comment: Did you try ProxyProvider?

Answer (score 1):

thanks Remi,

this is the key:

```dart
final user = await ref.watch(userProfileProvider.future)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```dart
final programProvider = FutureProvider<HopeProgram>((ref) async {
  final repository = ref.read(hopeRepositoryProvider);
  final user = await ref.watch(userProfileProvider.future);  
  HopeProgram program = await repository.getCurrentWeekProgram(user.currentWeek); // does not work, the compile complain
  return program;
});
```